# gcc -pthread no such fiile or directory ex_thread_creation

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to print infinite lines "Hello, how are you", "I'm fine, and you"

first I use command "vim ex_thread_creation"
then I enter following the code:

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
void *thread_print(void * messenge)
{    
    while(1) {          
    printf("Hello, How are you?\n");  
             }  
}  

int main() 
{    
pthread_t idthread;     
pthread_create( &idthread,NULL, &thread_print, NULL);   
while(1) { 
         printf("I’m fine, and you?\n");  
         }     
return 0;  
}
```

then I use `gcc ex_thread_creation.c -pthread ex_thread_creation`
then I meet the error: no such file or directory ex_thread_creation.

someone help me, please

edit 1: after I change -pthread to -o I meet another error: ex_thread_creation.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to pthread_create collect2: error: old returned 1 exit status

Comment: Need a `-o ex_thread_creation`. The `-o` option tells the compiler to use the value as the binary name.

Comment: -lpthread not -pthread

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your approach.

Regarding your `gcc` issue, the correct command would be:

```sh
gcc ex_thread_creation.c -o ex_thread_creation -lpthread
```

The `-o` flag stands for `outfile` or the file resulted from compiling the source file.

Regarding your code there are several issues too other than your code indentation.

The lines "Hello, how are you" and "I'm fine, and you" might not appear one after the other as intended. The output may appear malformed (the lines being intertwined) or the order could be wrong (Hello -> Hello -> I'm fine -> I'm fine).

If you want to keep the output as intended in your question, I suggest you use [synchronization mechanisms](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init).

Answer (score 2):

After research a bit longer, I've found the correct command is:

```
gcc -pthread -o term term.c
```